# Appending one file to other file using windows cmd prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm trying to append a file to another file and below is what I'm trying.

```
C:\Users\Desktop>type ./file1.txt >> ./file2.txt.txt
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

How do I fix this? any equivalent command?

Comment: Try `type file1.txt >> file2.txt.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Your slashes are going in the wrong direction.
Try

```
type .\file1.txt >> .\file2.txt.txt
```

Or even

```
type file1.txt >> file2.txt.txt
```

Update: So it looks like it's specifically `type` that doesn't like the forward slash - I've just tried this and it works:

```
type .\file1.txt >> ./file2.txt.txt
```

The pipe seems fine with a forward slash... Maybe someone with more knowledge than me can explain why!

Comment: for some reason type doesnt seem to work, only echo works, any difference?

Comment: `type` works fine for me, and `echo` will simply print what follows the echo command, not the content of your file.